# Cannot pass Proxy around html element to appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic-proxy

I wrote a thin wrapper which gets passed a node created by `document.createElement` and adds a few methods. This wrapper is realized with a Proxy. All I do is catching some getters.

```
  return new Proxy(node, {
    get (target, prop) {
      if (prop === 'node') return target

      if (wFuncs[prop]) {
        return Reflect.get(target, wFuncs[prop]).bind(target)
      }

      return Reflect.get(target, prop)
    }
  })
```

I would have expected to be able to pass such a proxy to `appendChild` since it is still an instance of `Node` and has all the properties and methods from an html element.
However, appendChild comlpains that the passed element is not a Node:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can redeclare global appendChild behavior. Like this:

1. Create internal `__element` property, that returns a real node

```js
return new Proxy(node, {
        get (target, prop) {
          if (prop === 'node') return target
          if (prop === '__element') return node
    
          if (wFuncs[prop]) {
            return Reflect.get(target, wFuncs[prop]).bind(target)
          }
    
          return Reflect.get(target, prop)
        }
      });
```

2. Change global appendChild

```js
Node.prototype.appendChild = function (el) {
  if (el["__element"]) {
    return _appendChild.call(this, el["__element"]);
  } else {
    return _appendChild.call(this, el);
  }
};
```

Comment: `appendChild` is only one of all the Dom methods which doesn't work with a proxy. The goal wasn't to rewrite them all